# removing more than a character using cut

Tags: django, django-templates

So I'm trying to search for Elements using query selector, the problem is, due to the way theses IDs are generated (with the name of regions, stores, and sale type, from the context) some of then includes spaces or dots on them which don't let them be searched.
I have identified the spaces were breaking my searches before and used cut to remove the spaces from IDs.
Is there a way to use cut to remove diferent characters as if I'm using cascaded replaces (in python) or replaceAlls (in JS) to make these ids don't have any spaces or dots? I tried using pipes but it didn't work. how can I do it?

Snippet of the formation of the elements:

```
{% if data.nivel == "N0" %}
    <tr id="family_{{ data.familia_produto|cut:" " }}" class="bu_name_line {{ data.nivel }} title0" 
    data-level="{{ data.nivel }}" data-family="{{ data.familia_produto }}"
    data-regional="{{ data.nome_regional }}" data-segment="{{ data.segmento }}" 
    data-bu-name="{{ data.nome_filial }}" onclick="show_lines('N1','{{ data.familia_produto }}')">

    <td id='bu_name' onmouseenter='hight_light(this)' onmouseleave='hight_light(this)'>
        {{ data.familia_produto }}
    </td>
            
{% elif data.nivel == "N1" %}
        <tr id="regional_{{ data.familia_produto|cut:" " }}_{{ data.nome_regional|cut:" " }}" 
        class="bu_name_line {{ data.nivel }} title1 hide" data-level="{{ data.nivel }}" 
        data-family="{{ data.familia_produto }}" data-regional="{{ data.nome_regional }}" 
        data-segment="{{ data.segmento }}" data-bu-name="{{ data.nome_filial }}"
        onclick="show_lines('N2A','{{ data.familia_produto }}','{{ data.nome_regional }}')">

        <td id='bu_name' onmouseenter='hight_light(this)' onmouseleave='hight_light(this)'>
            {{ data.nome_regional }}
        </td>
```

Snippet of the selection I'm trying to do to catch this elements:

```
 if (level_name[0] == 'family'){
            var forecast_lines = line.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id*=regional_${level_name[1]}]`)
            
            
        }else if (level_name[0]  == 'regional'){
            
            var forecast_lines = line.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id*=filial_${level_name[1]}_${level_name[2]}]`)
            
            
        }else if (level_name[0]  == 'filial'){
            //console.log("entrei aqui 222222222")
            var forecast_lines = line.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id*=segmento_${level_name[1]}_${level_name[2]}_${level_name[3]}]`)
```

error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Element.querySelectorAll: '[id*=segmento_CAFES_INTERNA_GER.INT.COMERCIAL]' is not a valid selector

Comment: the community will be glad to help you if you can share snippets of the code with the problem.

Comment: @enesislam just did

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how is your code but it will give you an idea:

```
should_removed_list = [" ", ".", ",", "="]
for i in should_removed_list:
    if str(i) in your_content:
        your_content.replace(str(i), "")
```